# Project Euler 16 2^1000 i got 1319?

Tags: c++

i checked the answer and it's not off by much from my answer, but it is still an error. can someone check my coding to see what mistake caused me to get a value of 1319?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int k = 0;
int o = 0;
vector<int> n(1,0);
n[0] = 1;
while (k < 1001)
{
    for (int l = 0; l < n.size(); l++)
        n[l] = n[l] * 2;
    for (int l = 0; l < n.size(); l++)
    {
        if (n[l] >= 1000000)
        {
            int m;
            if (l == n.size() - 1)
                n.resize(n.size() + 1);
            m = n[l] / 1000000;
            n[l] = n[l] % 1000000;
            n[l+1] = n[l+1] + m;
        }
    }
    k++;
}
for (int l = 0; l < n.size(); l++)
    o = o + int (n[l]/1000000) + int ((n[l] % 1000000) / 100000) + int ((n[l] % 100000) / 10000) + int ((n[l] % 10000) / 1000) + int ((n[l] % 1000) / 100) + int ((n[l] % 100) / 10) + n[l] % 10;
cout << o;
cin >> k;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why don't you post the question here instead of just saying `Project Euler #16` ?

Comment: Integer overflows = undefined behavior.

Comment: You're using all kinds of floating point operations but all your variables are `int`-s. You have overflow and rounding issues.

Comment: @xxbbcc where do you see floating point operations? There is not a single floating point number involved here. Nor any overflow, if `int` is the usual 32 bits.

Comment: Boy there are times when something like python is handy: `print sum(map(int, str(2**1000)))`

Comment: @NathanErnst Don't know how to use python :( i knew there are a lot of euler project problems that gets really ugly in c++ but can be solved in single lines of python. wish i'll get to learn that soon.

Comment: Not to imply knowing/learning how to do this in c++ is bad, but a trait of a great engineer is having a large toolbox and knowing when to use the appropriate tool.  C++ doesn't natively support large numbers, so this in an inherently difficult problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it

```
while (k < 1000)
```

in the outer loop condition.

In the `while` loop, you start with a representation of `2^k` in the vector with the value `k` has at entering the loop. So you are actually computing `2^1001` and not `2^1000`.

Comment: oh, thanks. that worked and gets me the right result. checked all the other numbers but forgot to tinker with this one... :P

Answer (score 0):

Problem of solving this in c++ is datatype limit, "int" is not sufficient to calculate 2^1000.
I have solved a prototype for this i.e. sum of the digits of number 2^4.The power 2^4 is 16 and sum of digits id 7.
Hope the code guides u.

```
         #include<iostream.h>
         #include<conio.h>

         void main()
             {
                 int count=1;

           int power=1;
                 int sum=0;
   while(count<=4)
   {   count++;
   power=power*2;

    }
   cout<<"The power is"<<power<<"\t";

    while(power!=0)
     {
           int digit=power%10;
        sum=sum+digit;
        power=power/10;

     }


     cout<<"The sum of digits is"<<sum;
     getch();
    }
```

Comment: as you may have noticed from my code, the problem is not in the data type format. i already have separated the number into trunks of k*10^n in an array. the problem is explained by the comment above